# contextMenuInteraction on UIButton

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

### What I want to do:

I have a `UITableViewCell` with 4 `UIButton`s. I want to be able to long press on any one of the buttons and peek display a `ViewController` with different data based on which button was interacted with.

### What I have tried:

```
@available(iOS 13.0, *)
func contextMenuInteraction(_ interaction: UIContextMenuInteraction, configurationForMenuAtLocation location: CGPoint) -> UIContextMenuConfiguration? {

    let location = interaction.location(in: tableView)
    guard let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForRow(at: location) else {
        return nil
    }

    guard let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) else {
        return nil
    }

    guard let button = cell.hitTest(location, with: nil) as? UIButton else {
        return nil
    }

    let stuff : [String : Any] = ["tag" : button.tag as NSNumber, "indexPath" : indexPath as IndexPath]

    let config = UIContextMenuConfiguration(identifier: stuff as NSCopying) { () -> UIViewController? in
        return ProfitSpreadsheetViewController()
    }

    return config

}

@available(iOS 13.0, *)
func contextMenuInteraction(_ interaction: UIContextMenuInteraction, previewForHighlightingMenuWithConfiguration configuration: UIContextMenuConfiguration) -> UITargetedPreview? {

    guard let stuff = configuration.identifier as? [String : Any] else {
        return nil
    }

    if let tag = stuff["tag"] as? Int {

        guard let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: stuff["indexPath"] as! IndexPath) else {
            return nil
        }

        if let button = cell.viewWithTag(tag) {
            return UITargetedPreview(view: button)
        }
    }

    return nil
}
```

### What isn't working:

No subviews of the `UITableViewCell` are responding to a long press and none of the delegate methods are called. I tried an alternate version of this code where I use the `tableView` context menu delegate methods, but that only worked when I long pressed on the actual cell, and not any of its subviews (such as a `UIButton`), which is what led me to this approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### iOS 14 version:

When you create the buttons, you can add a context menu to each one with the `menu` property, like this:

```swift
let destruct = UIAction(title: "Destruct", attributes: .destructive) { _ in }
let button = UIButton()
button.menu = UIMenu(title: "", children: [destruct])
```

This works even inside a table view (as per my testing).

### iOS 13 version

Unfortunately, `menu` is only available in iOS 14, but there's a workaround you can use. You'll need to create a custom `UIButton` subclass where you manually add a context menu interaction.

```swift
class ContextMenuButton: UIButton {
    var previewProvider: UIContextMenuContentPreviewProvider?
    var actionProvider: UIContextMenuActionProvider?

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setup()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        setup()
    }

    func setup() {
        let interaction = UIContextMenuInteraction(delegate: self)
        addInteraction(interaction)
    }

    public override func contextMenuInteraction(_ interaction: UIContextMenuInteraction, configurationForMenuAtLocation location: CGPoint) -> UIContextMenuConfiguration? {
        UIContextMenuConfiguration(
            identifier: nil,
            previewProvider: previewProvider,
            actionProvider: actionProvider
        )
    }
}
```

When you create your buttons you need to manually set the action and preview

```swift
let destruct = UIAction(title: "Destruct", attributes: .destructive) { _ in }
let button = ContextMenuButton()
button.actionProvider = { _ in
    UIMenu(title: "", children: [destruct])
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. A couple of questions. Can you explain how I would be able to identify the indexPath of the cell the button is on? And lastly, could you kindly provide an example displaying a view controller preview. I think it would be handled the same, but it would be helpful!

Comment: Depends on what you're trying to achieve. You could have an `indexPath` property on the cell and set it on creation, but I wouldn't recommend that as it breaks the separation of concerns.

Another option is have a function `contextMenuConfiguration(for indexPath: IndexPath)` in the view controller and in there create the menu items and preview based on the index path. You then use that when creating the cell and pass it on. 

As for the preview, there's a `previewProvider` property in the button, which you can set to whatever view controller want the preview to be.

Comment: With regards to your first suggestion, I would call that function in cellForRow and then retrieve the cell for the passed index path, and do the button menu stuff? Let me give it a shot. I’ll update you with my progress if that’s alright.

Comment: How can I assign the previewProvider in the contextMenuConfiguration(for indexPath: IndexPath) function if cell is immutable?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/smeshko/48d9675d25c0b509ba099699ac97dc15
Here's an example implementation, it should be enough to get you started on any additional functionality you want to introduce.

Comment: in this solution, instead of long pressing, can we show menu on a single tap? I am struggling to implement a custom button which is pill shaped (has an icon and a text horizontally) which responds to button tap and shows context menu. Can someone modify the above code to respond to the single tap to show context menu?